# realloc bug - incrementing last element of array

Tags: c, memory-management, realloc

I am trying to implement a dinamically increasing array with `realloc`. I create the array with `malloc`, and then call my `add` function, which increases the array size by 1. Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int *foo;
int quantity;

void add(int number) {
    foo = (int*) realloc(foo, sizeof(foo) + sizeof(int));
    foo[quantity] = number;
    quantity++;
}

void debugFoo() {
    for (int i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
        printf("foo[%i] = %i\n", i, foo[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main() {
    quantity = 3;
    foo = (int*) malloc(quantity * sizeof(int));

    foo[0] = 1;
    foo[1] = 2;
    foo[2] = 3;

    debugFoo();

    add(20);
    debugFoo();
    add(2);
    debugFoo();

    return 0;
}
```

However when I run it, I get the following output:

```
foo[0] = 1
foo[1] = 2
foo[2] = 3

foo[0] = 1
foo[1] = 2
foo[2] = 3
foo[3] = 20

foo[0] = 1
foo[1] = 2
foo[2] = 3
foo[3] = 21
foo[4] = 2
```

As you can see, the value of foo[3] is incremented by 1 the second time I call `add`. And the odd thing is that it is only incremented if the first value passed to `add` is even. Changing line 30 to `add(21)`, I get the following output:

```
[...]
foo[2] = 3
foo[3] = 21

foo[0] = 1
foo[1] = 2
foo[2] = 3
foo[3] = 21
foo[4] = 2
```

Is this a bug or am I using `realloc` wrong?

Comment: You need not cast malloc result. you may change  `foo = (int*) malloc(quantity * sizeof(int));` to `foo = malloc(quantity * sizeof *foo);`

Comment: [Compiler Bug](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?CompilerBug)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sizeof(foo)` is not the size of allocated buffer but the size of `foo`, which is `int*`. Use saved number of elements to calculate new buffer size.

```
foo = (int*) realloc(foo, sizeof(int) * (quantity + 1));
```

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof(foo)` is returning you always the same value, probably 4. Because of sizeof operator is returning you the size of `int *`

You have "correctly" declared a global scope variable (`quantity`) that store the current size of your array, use that variable to `realloc` your structure, as you did with `malloc`.

```
void add(int number) {
    quantity++;
    foo = realloc(foo, (quantity * sizeof(int)) );
    if (foo != NULL)
    {
       foo[quantity-1] = number;
    }
    else
    {
       fprintf(stderr, "Failed to add number.\n");
    }
}
```

Take note that is very important to always check functions return values.
As shown in my example for returned value of `realloc` you must do the same for `malloc` in `main` function.

```
int main() {
    quantity = 3;
    foo = malloc(quantity * sizeof(int));
    if (foo != NULL)
    {
       foo[0] = 1;
       foo[1] = 2;
       foo[2] = 3;

       debugFoo();

       add(20);
       debugFoo();
       add(2);
       debugFoo();

       return 0;
    }
    else
    {
       fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate array.\n");
       return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: @MikeCAT I badly pressed "Post Your Answer" button... :)

Comment: @LPs, one nice option in such cases is to delete the answer, edit it and undelete it, Helps you avoid the influx of downvotes for an unintentional mistake. Saved me at times. :)